# Git: How do I remove files listed in git status -s with "??", these are files I added to local repo?

Tags: git

I have a few files in my git status -s listed as,

> ?? file1
>
> ?? filepath/file2
>
> ?? file3
>
> ?? filepath/file4

I have been ignoring these and going along committing, pushing, pulling, and I am at the point where there are too many of these in my status report.

I tried git rm file1. It doesn't work. It says fatal path doesn't match any files.

Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, if you run `git status` without the `-s` parameter, you get an explanation that these are untracked files - that form is probably more helpful if the output of `git status -s` is confusing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are untracked files, i.e. the files which are present in your file system, but you've never added them to your repository by `git add`.

If you don't need them, you can just `rm` them. Or simply `git clean -fd` if you want to delete them all. If you want to do some filtering before removing them, you can do:

```
git ls-files -o --exclude-standard | grep 'my custom filter' | xargs rm
```

If you want to keep those files, but want `git status` to ignore them, add them to `.gitignore` file. Read `man gitignore` for the details.

Comment: I did git clean -fd and it removed all but one it seems to be a directory. ?? file/ @dmedvinsky

Comment: Well, the `-d` flag was supposed to tell git to delete untracked directories as well. Maybe there is separate git repository in there? Check for the `file/.git` directory presence.

Comment: If you want it to be removed as well, you can use `-f` option twice, as the `git help clean` says. I.e. `git clean -dff`.

Comment: Call me paranoid, but I much prefer `git clean -n`; Look at the output very very carefully, *then* `git clean -fd`.

Comment: You can also use `git status | grep "condition" | xargs rm`

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily add those to your `.gitignore`file so they won't show up in your `git status` and you don't accidentally add them.

That `git rm file` doesn't work because those files have not been added to your repository so there is nothing to delete

Answer (score 0):

These files are untracked, hence `git rm` does not work (it is the command to remove files from Git's control). You essentially have two options:

- Ignore these files. Read [gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). You can either add the ignore patterns to a `.gitignore` file that you can commit and share with your co-workers, or in a per-repo `.git/info/exclude`, or in a per-user `.config/git/ignore` file.
- Delete these files. Any tool you use to delete files when you're not using Git would work. Additionally, Git provides you [git clean](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) to help you in this task.

Answer (score 0):

I use this way and it was work for me:

```
git status | grep file | xargs rm
```